# Angular 2 unit test code in between function call and promise

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a function that changes status to inactivate button while it's executing. However, I'm not able to detect these changes, I can get the value before the function is called or after the promise is resolved, but not while it's in between these 2 ocasions.

This is the login function:

```
onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: Login, valid: boolean }) {
    if (valid) {
        this.isSubmiting = true;

        this.loginService.apiPost('signin', value).subscribe((response) => {
            this.isSubmiting = false;

            if ( response.success ) {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
        }, (error) => {
            this.isSubmiting = false;
        })
    }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to test this:

```
it('should show status "submitting" when button is clicked and form is valid', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'onSubmit');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    button.click();
    expect(component.isSubmiting).toBeFalsy();

    component.loginForm.controls['email'].setValue(formEmail);
    component.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue(formPassword);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    button.click();
    expect(component.isSubmiting).toBeTruthy();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.isSubmiting).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

But the expect to be truthy is returning false. What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: The problem is that this is not unit test. Too many moving parts are involved - loginService, router, DOM... and more importantly, it's not clear if they've got any special treatment (request mocking, RouterTestingModule, etc) - because they should get it. It can be considered integration or functional test, and such tests shouldn't be performed without full coverage with unit tests. Often they shouldn't be performed at all, because unit+e2e tests can provide necessary coverage.

Comment: @estus Do you have any recomendation on this? I'm very new to automated tests. I'm already mocking the services and router in a general way, i have a general TestModule, used only for tests with the router and services needed already mocked.

Comment: If you're mocking them, consider provide all the necessary details in the question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I would personally suggest to go with https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#isolated-v-testing-utilities for unit tests. With totally mocked router and everything else but tested unit. If you're testing onSubmit function, call it directly.